# Paste String Indexing For Vector

Tags: r, paste

This is my example code attempt

```
  paste(1:2,"x",0:1)
```

This is the output

```
[1] "1x0" "2x1"
```

But this is my Desired output:

```
[1] "1x0" "1x1" "2x0" "2x1"
```

Comment: Try `paste(rep(1:2,each=2),"x",0:1,sep = "")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `expand.grid`

```
apply(expand.grid(1:2,"x",0:1),1,paste,collapse="")
[1] "1x0" "2x0" "1x1" "2x1"
```